# Does a VsphereVM always have a parent host and folder?

Tags: jvm, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere, vmware-fusion

As the title says. I'm working with vsphere and I'm curious about how vmware objects related to each other. When you have a vmware virtual machine, will it always have a folder and host that it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order for a VM to exist as an object in the vCenter server (as well as a standalone ESXi host) it will need to have at least a parent host, resource pool, inventory folder, and datastore.